# Solr 9.0.0 [doc=null] missing required field in case of Partial Atomic Update - Bug in Solr code

Tags: solr, solr9

In Apache Solr 9.0.0 while performing partial update it give below error

`[doc=null] missing required field: id`

This happens even after providing id field which is uniquefield as well.

While investigating we saw that it this error occurs because of below dynamicField defination in schema

`<dynamicField name="*" type="text_general" indexed="false" stored="false" multiValued="false" docValues="false"/>`

if we change dynamicField name to have suffix then it works fine, like `name="*_i"`
But without changing dynamicField definition is there way to make partial atomic update work ?

**UPDATE**
Found the commit in Solr which caused this - https://github.com/apache/solr/commit/5a9a34daedb34cb5fc5dc6f8c5c40a734bb7dacb?diff=split
Bug is in JsonLoader. It got introduced in Solr 9.0.0

Workaround is to send Atomic Partial update in xml format instead of JSON -

```
<add>
  <doc>
    <field name="id">1011</field>
    <field name="CLIENT_TEAM" update="set">New Delhi</field>
  </doc>
  <doc>
    <field name="id">1022</field>
    <field name="CLIENT_TEAM" update="set">Mumbai</field>
  </doc>
</add>
```

Comment: After some more investigation it seems Solr considers “set” keyword in partial update as field name if schema has dynamicField with name=“*” or even if you define <field name=“set” …> partial update wont work as then Solr effectively treats partial update request as child document.      E.g partial update request - [{“id”: “101”, “client_name”: {“set” : “new name”}}]

Comment: Thanks.  Can you please point me to a bug if there is already one open?

Comment: No I didn't raise any bug but added comment in the code repo and had conversation over mail with David Smiley who made those changes and he agrees to the bug as well.